# How can i play ios apps on PC?

Tags: windows, ios, windows-10, iphone-app

hi guys i need a software for play **ios** apps on **Pc**

---

so whats your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a very good PC to run an iOS simulator. You will find a few if you Google it. I personally worked for a short time with the Xamarin TestFlight and I wasn’t impressed from the performance.